# Modify a global variable based on an object property

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn object oriented javascript and ran into the following problem:

I have an object constructor (is that the right term?) like this:

```
function itemCreator(itemName, itemType, itemPositionX, itemPositionY) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
            this.itemType = itemType;
            this.itemPositionX = itemPositionX;
            this.itemPositionY = itemPositionY;
            allItems.push(this); //store all items in a global variable
            }//end itemCreator;


//then I use it to create an object

megaRocket = new itemCreator (
           'megarocket',
           'item_megarocket',
           108,
           475
           )
```

Now I realised I also need to map these objects to modify different global variables based on which "itemType" the object has. This is where I am stuck. How can I make a global variable that only objects with a specific itemType property can modify?

For example I would like to create an object that increments a variable called amountOfMegarockets, but only if the itemType for that object is "item_megarocket".

I later plan on looping an array of these items to see if player object touches them (to collect the item):

```
function checkForItems(){ 
                var itemLen =allItems.length;
                for (i=0; i < itemLen; i++){
                var itemObject = allItems[i];

                if ( //checking for "collisions" here
                (ship.x < (itemObject.itemBitmap.x + itemObject.size) &&  (ship.x + shipWidth) > itemObject.itemBitmap.x) &&
                (ship.y < (itemObject.itemBitmap.y + itemObject.size) &&  (ship.y + shipWidth) > itemObject.itemBitmap.y)
                ){
                itemObject.actor.y = -500; //just removing the item from canvas here (temporary solution)
                // Here comes pseudo code for the part that I'm stuck with  
                variableBasedOnItemObject.itemType++;

                }
```

I hope my explanation makes sense to someone!

EDIT:

Bergi's answer makes most sense to me, but I can't get the syntax right. Here's how I'm trying to use Bergi's code:

```
var amounts = {},
allItems = [];
function itemCreator(itemName, itemType, itemPositionX, itemPositionY) {
this.itemName = itemName;
this.itemType = itemType;
this.itemPositionX = itemPositionX;
this.itemPositionY = itemPositionY;

(amounts[itemType]=2); // this is different from bergi's example because I need to set the initial value of the item to two
//I also shouldn't increase the item amount on creation of the item, but only when it's specifically called from another function
this.increaseCount = amounts[itemType]++; //this should IMO increase the itemType amount inside the amounts object when called, but it doesn't seem to work
}

//creating the object the way bergi suggested:
allItems.push(new itemCreator('shootUp001', 'item_up', 108, 475));
```

Now here's the problematic part:

```
function checkForItems(){ 
                var itemLen =allItems.length;
                for (i=0; i < itemLen; i++){
                var itemObject = allItems[i];

                if ( my condition here)
                ){

//code below is not increasing the value for the current itemType in the amounts object. 
//Probably a simple syntax mistake?
                itemObject.itemType.increaseCount; 

                }

           }

           }
```

Why is my call of itemObject.itemType.increaseCount; not increasing the value of amounts.itemType?

Comment: IMO, this isn't the right approach at all. You should separate your logic into different classes, not under one monolithic class.

Comment: It's not a monolith class IMO, because all the "items" are very similar and share the same properties. The only main difference between different items should be the counter variable they affect.

Comment: Any question starting with "modify global variable" is already asking the wrong question.

Comment: @IngoBürk +100 to that!

Comment: @IngoBürk Ok so how should I handle a situation in which several different functions need to read the same variable?

Comment: There are many ways. You could pass the variable (or objects holding the variable). You can just as well use the pattern you used, but you should do it in your own, local scope, not in the global scope. A very easy way is usig self-invoked functions to create a local scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Increment a global variable called amountOfMegarockets, but only if the itemType for that object is "item_megarocket".

Don't use a global variable for each of those item types. Do use one object (in global or local scope) which counts the amouts of each type on its properties.

```
var amounts = {},
    allItems = [];
function Item(itemName, itemType, itemPositionX, itemPositionY) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.itemType = itemType;
    this.itemPositionX = itemPositionX;
    this.itemPositionY = itemPositionY;

    amounts[itemType]++ || (amounts[itemType]=1); // count by type
    allItems.push(this); // store all items
}
```

Notice that I wouldn't put all `Item` instances in an array by default, better omit that line and let it do the caller:

```
allItems.push(new Item('megarocket', 'item_megarocket', 108, 475));
```

Comment: Hi! This seems promising, I will start testing it now. If you have the time, could you explain the line with
    amounts[itemType]++ || (amounts[itemType]=1);
That looks to me like you are incrementing the variable every time this function is used? Also, is the "or" statement (the right side part of that line) simply an another option or is it also used in practice?

Comment: I feel like I'm almost there, but I can't seem to find the correct syntax for modifying the "amount" object. I'll edit my question to better show how I'm trying to use your solution (without luck)!

Comment: In your code, `.itemType` is a constant property with the literal name "itemType". In my code, I'm using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) to get a dynamic property name from the `itemType` value. Yes, I'm incrementing that property every time the constructor runs. The OR-part is executed when the left part evaluates to `NaN` because the property was undefined before. More explicit: `if (itemType in amounts) amouts[itemType]++; else amounts[itemType] = 1;`

Comment: Ouch now my head really hurts: aren't we both using itemType almost in the same manner in the constructor function? Or are you talking about my old code? I edited a new version of my code below in my question with your suggestions included.

Comment: I was referring to your code from `checkForItems`, in the one of the `Item` constructor you have used bracket notation correctly. But you seem to initialize (reset) the amount with `2` every time the constructor is invoked - that's why I've used a condition (which was hidden in the OR-expression).

Comment: Okay now I start to understand! I will quickly test some more and then accept your answer.

Comment: Dang it I just can't get it right. Sorry for being such a PITA! Can you please explain the correct syntax of calling the created object in order to increase the amounts. This doesn't seem to do it: 
itemObject.itemType.increaseCount; 
I will accept your answer anyways now, because I'm sure it's correct and I just don't get the syntax of calling the amounts[itemType]++ properly.

Comment: I think you're looking for `amounts[itemObject.itemType]++` now (assuming the `amounts` object has already been properly initialized, like `var amounts = {"item_megarocket": 0, …};`).

Answer (score 0):

you can do some things like

```
(function (global) {
    // create a scope
    var allItems = [];
    global.itemCreator = function(itemName, itemType, itemPositionX, itemPositionY) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemType = itemType;
        this.itemPositionX = itemPositionX;
        this.itemPositionY = itemPositionY;
        allItems.push(this); //store all items in a global variable
        }//end itemCreator;
})(this);
```

this will work. but seriously dont complicate too mutch your code juste to make private var. if someone want to cheat using debugger he will always found a way to do it.

---- edit
If you juste want access to global var base on itemType you can do some thing like:

```
function checkForItems(){ 
    var itemLen =allItems.length;
    for (i=0; i < itemLen; i++){
        var itemObject = allItems[i];

        if ( //checking for "collisions" here
            (ship.x < (itemObject.itemBitmap.x + itemObject.size) &&  (ship.x + shipWidth) > itemObject.itemBitmap.x) &&
            (ship.y < (itemObject.itemBitmap.y + itemObject.size) &&  (ship.y + shipWidth) > itemObject.itemBitmap.y)
        ){
            itemObject.actor.y = -500; //just removing the item from canvas here (temporary solution)
            // Here comes pseudo code for the part that I'm stuck with  
            if (window[itemObject.itemType + "Data"])) {
                variableBasedOnItemObject.itemType++;
            } else {
                window[itemObject.itemType + "Data"] = {
                    itemType: 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. Say there is a global variable called "amountOfMegarockets". How would I write a function that modifies that variable only when "this" has itemType of megaRocket?

Comment: ok. forget my answer. I do not have understand your question sorry. you can use string to access your var so you ca do somme things like: window["amountOf" + this.itemType + "s"].push(this) for example but take care of plural and that the object exist (ex: window.hasOwnProperty("amountOf" + this.itemType + "s")